# Не отображаеться меню при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: html, css

При нажатии на кнопку в navbar классу menu должен присваиваться класс menu-active и меню должно отобразиться но после присваивания класса меню не появляется в чём может быть проблема?

https://github.com/Tekeo-Ronin/skinali-factory

https://tekeo-ronin.github.io/skinali-factory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс у тебя почему-то добавляется вместе с точкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убери точку и все будет good.